# Gradle project dependency doesn't have transitive dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

So, the title is a bit badly phrased, but I have this project structure:

```
Project
+- A
   +- B
      +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.1
```

Where A and B are both subprojects of Project.

The problem is, when compiling A (B compiles fine), B is recompiled and outputs a jar with no dependencies (even if the shadowJar plugin is run).

Projects' (simplified) build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.1.0'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

    compileJava.finalizedBy(shadowJar)

    shadowJar {
        archiveClassifier.set('')
    }
}
```

A's (simplified) build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':B')
}
```

B's (simplified) build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.3.1'
}
```

So, the output shows that shadowJar is run, but still gives me this error:

```
error: cannot access Remapper 
class file for org.objectweb.asm.commons.Remapper not found
```

And the output jar in the build/libs folder of project B doesn't have ASM in it unless I only build project B.

The only other question I saw with this problem was for Android and used API instead of implementation (which I think is Android only).

So, how can I fix this problem and get Gradle to recognize (and shade) ASM?

EDIT:
After further testing, it seems to only break if A calls a method of B that depends on ASM.

A can import a class from B that imports Remapper with no error, the problem is only if said class extends Remapper.
I've found a band-aid fix by just implementing ASM in project A.

Comment: Still working on this, both IntelliJ's gradle and gradle CLI have the same problem. I've tried adding shadowJar to defaultTasks (read somewhere else that's what task is used on subprojects) but no luck.

Comment: Do you get the error at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Compile time, not runtime

Comment: Then try applying the [java-library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) and change `implementation` to `api` for the ASM dependency. This means it will expose it to project A at compile time (otherwise it is only exposed at runtime).